# Query for a user and then a specific object in an array with one mongoose query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[image]

I have a user object as shown above. I am trying to write a mongoose query that finds the user via the `req.user.id` and then queries their wishList array for a specific item with the id that matches the `req.params.id`

Here is my query:

```
let userWishListItem = await User.find({_id: req.user.id, 'wishList': {_id: req.params.id}})
```

`userWishListItem` just gives back the user currently. how can I get back the specific wishList object in their `wishList` array. Any advice would be great.

Comment: something like this ? https://mongoplayground.net/p/uXzXnjxeaPx

Comment: Your wish list is an array of object ids, you are querying with _id.
Did not get the question properly.

Comment: @sachin i'm not very well versed in mongoose, i'm trying to retrieve a specific wish list item from within this query that matches the ```req.params.id``` my question revolves around how to properly execute this within a query

Comment: Is there another collection of wishes from which you are adding the Ids in wish list ?